# How do I set up text replacement shortcuts in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to set up automatic text replacement shortcuts in Visual Studio Code similar to [snippets in SQL Complete](https://docs.devart.com/sqlcomplete/sql-code-snippets/using-sql-snippets.html) or [text replacements on iOS](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-text-replacements-iph6d01d862/ios). So for example: if I type `ssf` I want VS Code to replace it with `SELECT * FROM`. (Or alternatively, offer it as an autocomplete suggestion).

How can I set up automatic text replacement rules in VS Code?

Comment: use extension Hypersnips with auto replace

Answer (score 0):

you can use extensions such as the "JavaScript (ES6) code snippets"